# Dell inspiron laptop shut off during windows updates - non stop freezing

Tags: windows-7, laptop, freeze

My laptop had malware so I used windows restore to reset it to factory settings and it got rid of the malware.

Upon the next time shutting it off, windows updates said it had around 200 updates to do. A day and half later still not done and I needed to use my laptop so I just shut it off. Now every time I use it, it freezes non stop doing the most basic tasks and will stay frozen for hours. Is there anyway to fix this or is it permanently damaged?

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be that the large number of updates need time to get handled (compiled?):
Check if there is a task TrustedInstaller.exe that keeps running all the time. If so, give it another night or so to run (for my rather fast laptop, dot.net 4.5 alone took 9 hours to finish this, whatever it does). The process often comes back after reboots too, but it does make progress, and finally it will finish and go away, and it should be fast again.

That's just a try, it could be many other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic answer for this.

Firstly, you should check the cooling, the power supply, the memory and the harddisc.

I think you should run Ubuntu from USB for some hours. If it will run stable, you have a software problem, or your harddisk is broken.
If there is also a problem, you have to check your hardware.

Check

- Memory (memtest)
- Harddrive (using windows)
- System cooling